# How to control editing of UITextFields within custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a custom (subclass of) UITableViewCell with multiple UITextFields in it.

I would like to make it so that when the TableView is in editing mode, clicking the UITextField will enable editing of the TextField. However, when not in editing mode, clicking the cell (or any UITextField within it) selects the cell so I can control behavious through the didSelectCellAtIndexPath method.

What is the best way to go about this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way (and most elegant) is to override `setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` method of the cell:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    self.textField.enabled = editing;
}
```

Remember to call super if you need to inherit the behavior of the common UITableViewCell